# How to remove hidden plugins in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I have plug-in for VS 2008.
I cannot seem to figure out how to remove it.
It's liquid xml studio. The program it self cannot be uninstalled because it's not listed in the add/remove programs folder and the uninstall app is missing.

Answer (score 4):

Ok here's what I did.
I delete the folder `c:\Program Files\<bad plugin>`

Then ran: `Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Tools | Add-in Manager

seems to be it

Comment: Right, however it's not listed there. If it's not there is there any other spot?

Comment: @aron - if it's not listed in Add/Remove Programs, nost listed in the Start Menu and not showing in the Add-In Manager, what's making you think it's actually loaded?

Comment: when VS 2008 loads it's listed on the splash page as one of the plugins/addins
Also if I every try to open an .xsd file Liquid XML takes over and forces me to register it

Liquid XML Schema Editor   2.0.2.0


Liquid XPath Expression Builder   2.0.2.0
Allows XPath Expressions to be constructed and visualized

Comment: @aron http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/06/product-registration-for-the-about-box-in-visual-studio-2010-and-the-deprecation-of-ivsinstalledproduct-interface.aspx here is described how to get into that list. try reverse. you might need to edit registry.

Answer (score 0):

This was in VS 2012, after trying the other answers here ...

Try uninstalling it from add/remove programs. You may still have some cleaning up to do after that in Regedit...as an example, I removed HGSCC, after uninstalling it, by searching the registry for "hgscc". Some of the places I found it in... `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\InstalledProducts\`
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Packages`
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\...`

and also the guid clsid section. Visual Studio stopped complaining about it after I deleted all the registry folders that had all that junk in it the the uninstall should have removed. Make  sure you have a good look.